# How to handle JavaScript alert smartly with the message "Error: cannot read properties of null (reading 'scroll width')" in selenium

Tags: selenium

For the .net web application, I am facing disturbance like one JavaScript alert with the message "Error: cannot read properties of null (reading 'scroll width')" coming every time,
We handle it by using the user-defined method as follows:

```
    public void AlertHandler()
    {
        bool bCheck = true;
        if (IsAlertPresent(driver))
        {
            while (IsAlertPresent(driver))
            {
                IAlert Confirmation1 = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                GetAlertMessage = Confirmation1.Text;
                Confirmation1.Accept();               
                if (bCheck)
                {
                    WriteExcel();
                    bCheck = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to handle it for UI Automation with the use of selenium,

Are there any other smart ways? to handle it in Selenium like Globally we can declare that it will apply to all codes and will handle when this alert will be flaunting anywhere on any screen...

[Click here to see Javascript Alert which we are facing in the web application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s190.png)

Comment: How do you want to handle it? Do you want to ignore it?

Comment: @pguardiario can we bypass it? Or else how can we handle it? Like can we declare something globally and it will automatically detect automatically handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable window.alert like:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  window.alert = () => {}
""")
```

Comment: How to use the above thing? can we declare it globally or do we need to add it to that place where the alert is invoked?

Comment: window is a global object. You just replace window.alert before the thing that triggers alert. You need to do it again whenever the page navigates.